# How to do run:"python manage.py runserver in vscode.i want to run a new server for my project

Tags: python, server, django-manage.py

How to do run: `python manage.py runserver` in Visual Studio Code?

I get the below error

> "Can not open file manage.py:no such file or directory"

Comment: For windows......

Answer (score 1):

go to that folder where is you 'manage.py' file through cm

**Folder name**

and then run you command

> python3 manage.py runserver

Answer (score 0):

In vscode terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> hotkey) change path (with `cd` command) to directory where `manage.py` file of your project saved, and then run `python manage.py runserver`